# side by side text fields with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have text fields with label above the text fields and text fields to be side by side.

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="first_name" >first name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="first name" title="enter your first name if any.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="last_name" >Last name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="last name" title="enter your last name if any.">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="phone" >phone</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="enter phone" title="enter your phone number if any.">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="mobile" >mobile</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="enter mobile number" title="enter your mobile number if any.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="email" >email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" title="enter your email.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="password" >password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" title="enter your password.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label" for="password2" >password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="password2" title="enter your password2.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span class="lbl">User Agreement</span>
                </div>
            </div><br />
            <div class="form-actions">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i>
                        Register
                    </button>
                     &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-sm" type="reset">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

I am using Bootstrap 3, can anyone tell me how to get the text fields side by side with label above. Thanks.

Comment: What is the issue you're currently having? Can you create a fiddle to showcase this issue?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) (under the section, "Column sizing")

Comment: @badAdviceGuy - now I am getting label and textfield side by side when i tried to use the form-inline it got mess up. 
I am looking for something like this for example 
[https://idp.godaddy.com/shopper_new.aspx?ci=10530&spkey=GDSWNET-130506072552001&transferCart=true&shopper_id_old=]

Comment: @DominicBarnes - actually i want to know what i need to use to get the fields side by side and the label above the fields. any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `display:inline-block` for the div `form-group`.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/r8C82/)

CSS

```
.form-group{
    display:inline-block;
    width:45%; //Change as you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

It is not the best way but it should work. Try the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Froozen_Bel/mL4N7/)

Add this to your css:

```
.control-label {
    text-align:left !important;
}
```

And this is the html:

```
<form class="form form-horizontal" action="##" method="post" id="registrationForm">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="first_name" >first name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="first name" title="enter your first name if any.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="last_name" >Last name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="last name" title="enter your last name if any.">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="phone" >phone</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="enter phone" title="enter your phone number if any.">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="mobile" >mobile</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="enter mobile number" title="enter your mobile number if any.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="email" >email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" title="enter your email.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="password" >password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password" title="enter your password.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                <label class="col-xs-12 control-label" for="password2" >password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="password2" title="enter your password2.">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span class="lbl">User Agreement</span>
                </div>
            </div><br />
            <div class="form-actions col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i>
                        Register
                    </button>
                     &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <button class="btn btn-sm" type="reset">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></i>
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Comment: here i got one issue is the label are getting on right side above the field.

Answer (score 0):

Put your labels inside the `form-group`, and remove the `col-xs-2` from the labels:

http://www.bootply.com/125656